# How to create a chart in ASP.NET using SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I want to create a bar chart, that displays which columns has the most values.

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN radioButtonLog = 1 THEN 1 END) AS 'Super Happy', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN radioButtonLog = 2 THEN 1 END) AS 'Happy', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN radioButtonLog = 3 THEN 1 END) AS 'Normal', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN radioButtonLog = 4 THEN 1 END) AS 'Sad',
    SUM(CASE WHEN radioButtonLog = 5 THEN 1 END) AS 'Super Sad'
FROM 
    tblMessage
```

[image]

This is the output - now I want to display these values in a chart.

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Super Happy" YValueMembers="Super Happy"></asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series2" XValueMember="Happy" YValueMembers="Happy"></asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series3" XValueMember="Normal" YValueMembers="Normal"></asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series4" XValueMember="Sad" YValueMembers="Sad"></asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series5" XValueMember="Super Sad" YValueMembers="Super Sad"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

[image]

This is the output. I understand, that the XValueMember is wrong, because I put the same values as Y axis, but instead of displaying numbers in X axis, how can I display "Super Happy", "Happy", "Normal" etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding multiple Series to the chart, which is incorrect. You need to add a "Points" collection to the series, then a DataPoint for each result.

https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx <-- this is a good guide to using the chart component.